# better way to do the link for this scenario in html5

Tags: html, css

I have a combined link, then some text "and" and then another link like below.

DoctorandPatient

As the user wants to have like all these in underline.

*Doctor and Patient*

All good, but I was looking for a nicer way to do it. Because, the word "and" looks like a link when we hover over and it has same styles that we apply for link (custom ones). I want to know if there is a way to avoid applying style of link that we have to that and keyword but said that we need to have same one underline for the 3 words together.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could surround what you want to stylish with a  tag:

```
<a href="#"><span>Doctor</span> and <span>Patience</span></a>
```

Applying styles to these  should be trivial :).

Also, of course, you can write two separated links:

```
<a href="#">Doctor</a> and <a href="#">Patience</a>
```

Edit:
I've added a fiddle. This can be a possible solution.

https://jsfiddle.net/jomx8vyf/

Comment: Rafa, the problem is I have two different links (hrefs) and so cant use a single anchor and have two things an in two separated links, I want and also to be underlined

Comment: Then use the second form and surround it with a <div>, by example: <div><a href="#">Doctor</a> and <a href="#">Patience</a></div>. That div can be stylished with text-decoration: underline. I've updated my answer with a tiny fiddle. :)